# How to hide login form and show another component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am a novice in JavaScript and Mean stack frameworks. I am trying to build a web page where in the landing page should have a header and login form. If the user authenticates well, should be redirected to home page else redirected to the same landing page with some error like `Incorrect credentials`. I am facing an issue wherein I am able to authenticate the user but when I try to update the component for the homepage, it gets displayed below the login form and not replacing the login form. I need to replace login with home page content.

Below is my `app.component.ts`:

```js
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
    import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        //styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent {
        title = 'app';

        constructor(private loginService: LoginService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router) {
            console.log("Form Component Start");
        }

        onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
            var user = {
                email: form.controls['email'].value,
                password: form.controls['password'].value
            };

            this.loginService.authenticateAdmin(user).subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log("success status 200" + data.status);

                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
                },
                err => {
                    console.log("error status" + err.status);
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

This is my `login.service.ts`:

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from "@angular/http";
    import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class LoginService {

        constructor(private http: Http) { }
        // Uses Observable.forkJoin() to run multiple concurrent http.get() requests.
        // The entire operation will result in an error state if any single request fails.
        authenticateAdmin(user) {
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' });
            //let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); //tobe done

            let options = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headers });
            let body = this.serializeObj(user);
            alert(body);
            return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/admin/authenticate', body, options).map((res: Response) => {
                //res.json()
                console.log("hjk");
                let details = {detail:res.json(),status: res.status};
                return details;//Observable..throw(details);
            })
                 .catch((err: Response) => {
                    //let details = err.json();
                    //return Observable.throw(details);
                    console.log("jkll");

                    let details = {detail:err.json(),status: err.status};
                    return Observable.throw(details);
                });

        }

        private serializeObj(obj) {
            var result = [];
            for (var property in obj)
                result.push(encodeURIComponent(property) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[property]));

            return result.join("&");
        }
    }
```

Below is `home.component.ts`:

```js
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


    @Component({
      //selector: 'app-root',
      template: '<div>Welcome to home page</div>'
    })

    export class HomeComponent {
    }
```

This is my `app.component.html`:

```html
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navigation-clean-button" style="background-color:#294e80;height:70px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">Aao Padhe - Admin UI</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="login-clean">
    <div>
        <form #loginform = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(loginform)" style="height:441px;">
            <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-navigate" style="color:#294e80;"></i></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" #email="ngModel" placeholder="Email" ngModel required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" #password="ngModel" placeholder="Password" ngModel required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" style="background-color:#294e80;">Log In</button>
            </div><a href="#" class="forgot" style="height:50px;">Forgot your email or password?</a></form>
    </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Header-Blue.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Login-Form-Clean.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Navigation-with-Button1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Registration-Form-with-Photo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body style="margin-left:0px;">
    <div></div>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

After login it looks like: 
[image: See welcome message below login]

Comment: Angular 2 has something called Route guard https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate maybe this can help accomplish what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an *ngIf on the components to hide/show depending on some condition which checks if the user if authenticated.

Try something like this...

```html
  <div *NgIf="!isAuthenticated()">
        <form #loginform = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(loginform)" style="height:441px;">
```

You would have to add the isAuthenticated function to your ts code of course.

*NgIf documentation is here https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: I was wondering if there is a more concise and neat way of doing it. But it helped. Accepting it as an answer.

Comment: so, my ngIf is there but somehow forms show up for fractions of a second and then vanished.

<div *ngIf="isLogin" id="welcome">
   <p>Welcom to rabbito</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isLogin" id="signup-form">
   <form [[formGroup]="signupForm">
    .....
    </form>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue and the way I handled it was by adding a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to my `app.component.html` file and my routes looked something like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./core/core.module').then((m) => m.CoreModule),
  },
];
```

login.component.ts

```
    onLogin() {
    const isUserValid = // Logic to check if credentials are correct
    if(isUserValid)
      this.router.navigateByUrl('dashboard');
    else
      return;
}
```

Through this the login form hid as soon as the user was valid and redirected to the dashboard module.